# facebook graph api error: An access token is required to request this resource

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to publish a link on the given profile on Facebook via the app. Post to https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/links with access_token and other necessary parameters.
For testing purpose, I got the access_token with Graph API Explorer and had the publish_stream and share_item extended permission.

Then I got the error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

I tried fb_id and fb_username for the PROFILE_ID but got the same error. Anything wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `/links` is read only. To create a link, you need to POST to `/USER_ID/feed`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links

Comment: It would be good to mention that in few weeks this would be possible only if user_id is the current user.